# Fetching Start & END of file with AWK is hitting Performance

Tags: awk

Trying to slice between Start to mid and mid to end of the file. Coding with `END` Command is hitting the performance of the script and it tends to take more time and `start_pos is hardcoded to 1`. What should be the better way to do this.

`Primarily three questions:`
1. Instead of hard-coding start position to 1, what would be more efficient way to start from 1st position
2. Instead of hard-coding END position to `END`, what would be more efficient way to start from 1st position
3. Defining the END position of the file invoking`END` command will hit the performance?``

Start Positioning Code:
`awk 'NR>= v1 & & NR<=v2' v1="${start_pos}" v2="${mid_pos}" file`

End Position code:
`awk 'NR>= v3 & & NR<=v4' v3="${next_mid}" v4="END" file`

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. Sorry but your question is unclear. What is your actual question? You talk about _hitting my performance_. What do you mean?

Comment: @kvantour updated the question again, ask is the `END` command to fetch the end of file is slowing down the script

Comment: you cannot set v2="END". This does nothing. Also, you set `v2="END"` which is not used in the script.

Comment: my bad, setting`v4=END`. Aim is to fetch till the end of file

Comment: I have added an answer, I don't know if it answers your question.

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are asking, but it sounds like you have a script that is making multiple passes on a file and using `awk` to find chunks of the file to work on.  Don't do that.  Read the file once.

Comment: Yes @WilliamPursell correct, can you please advise me a better way to do it. Appreciate your inputs on this and apologies for the delayed response

Comment: You haven't described the problem with enough detail to give a recommendation beyond "read the file only once".

Comment: @WilliamPursell my bad, please excuse. the need is to extract the line number by comparing files, presently its happening with `sed and egrep`
`line=`egrep -n file1 file2 | cut -d ":" -f1` ` and the outcome of line is being used to segregate the file later using sed
`sed -n "1, ${line}p" file >> output`. This is where the speed is slowing down since it has large number of files and its doing the same for all files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quickest way to slice a file is the following:

```
awk 'FNR>n{exit}(FNR>=m)' m=5 n=10 file
```

If you want to make it possible the method is generic and also works with the "END" of a file, you can do:

```
awk '(FNR<m){next}1;(FNR==n){exit}' m=5 n=10 file       # cut line 5 to 10
awk '(FNR<m){next}1;(FNR==n){exit}' m=5 n="EOF" file    # cut line 5 till EOF
awk '(FNR<m){next}1;(FNR==n){exit}' m=5 n=-1 file       # cut line 5 till EOF
awk '(FNR<m){next}1;(FNR==n){exit}' m=1 n=10 file       # cut line 1 till 10
awk '(FNR<m){next}1;(FNR==n){exit}' m=1 n=10 file       # cut line "BOF" till 10
```

The reason this works is because strings are converted to numeric ZERO when used with a numeric operator such as "`<` or `==` (the latter is numeric because `FNR` is an integer.

---

> **`FNR`:** record number of current file 
>   **`next`:** stop processing this record, and move to the next record in the file
>   **`exit`:** terminate any file processing, and execute `END` statement if available (there are none here)

Comment: thanks for your input, since I am not looking to hardcode values rather make it configurable by assigning variables. Hope I should be able to assign variables to the below:
`awk 'FNR>n{exit}(FNR>=m)' m="$start_pos" n="$mid_pos"  file`
`and`
`awk 'FNR>n{exit}(FNR>=m)' m="$nestmid_pos" n="EOF"  file`

something like this ?

Comment: you can do that, but the method you write down cannot be used to select the end of a file. the second method is better for that.It will also be fast. The `exit` ensures that you don't process the full file if you don't have too.

Comment: @kvavtour ok, in that case can you please advise a faster way to slice the first half of the file please. Unable to up-vote you since lacking reputation however thanks for your detailed help.

Comment: @Brown, I don't understand what you mean with _a faster way to slice the first half of the file_. All the above methods will work as fast.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to print a range of lines, `awk` is overkill. Using `sed`:

```
sed -n "${start_pos},${mid_pos}p; ${next_mid},\$p" file
```

If you don't want to print lines from `next_mid` to the end of the file, but to somewhere before the end, use a fourth line number variable:

```
sed -n "${start_pos},${mid_pos}p; ${next_mid},${next_end}p; ${next_end}q" file
```